# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str' error

Tags: python, pandas

#im working on an assignment on a covid 19 dataset and using the apriori algorithm to analyze it however i keep having problems with it and im VERY bad at programming
#i imported these libraries first

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
!pip install efficient_apriori
```

#load the data

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

#read the file and display it

```
df = pd.read_csv('covid_dataset.csv')
df
#did this to turn the dataframe to a tuple
records = df.to_records(index=False)
result = list(records)
```

#here is the problem

```
from efficient_apriori import apriori
min_support = 7/len(result) 
min_confidence = 0
itemsets, rules = apriori(result, min_support=min_support, min_confidence=min_confidence)
```

#here is the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e29e44a028ef> in <module>()
      6 # For now set min_confidence = 0 to obtain all the rules
      7 min_confidence = 0
----> 8 itemsets, rules = apriori(result, min_support=min_support, min_confidence=min_confidence)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/efficient_apriori/itemsets.py in itemsets_from_transactions(transactions, min_support, max_length, verbosity, output_transaction_ids)
    312         # Retrieve the itemsets of the previous size, i.e. of size k - 1
    313         # They must be sorted to maintain the invariant when joining/pruning
--> 314         itemsets_list = sorted(item for item in large_itemsets[k - 1].keys())
    315 
    316         # Gen candidates of length k + 1 by joining, prune, and copy as set

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

Comment: I don't know why it happens but I would look closer at the data you're putting into the apriori function - since it's not expecting a string and an ndarray to be mixed in the same column, I guess. And maybe that's a problem with the data you put in?